# set vertical alignment of text(link) center with respect to its background image?

Tags: html, css

Using css, I gave a background color to a link and set some height and width.
Using "text-align: center"  property, text(link) was aligned center horizontally, but how do I align it center vertically with respect to its background color. Its stuck on the top of box.

Answer (score 0):

set `line-height` equal to `height` it will automatically centers the `text` of `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add some line height to your div

```
 div
 {
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

or you can use display :table-cell

```
div {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align: center;
  }
```